# How to calculate and display sum total balance into main account from three different balance section (sign-up bonus, deposit, referral ) in LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-9, laravel-controller

I want to display the sum total of all credit activities in a user account as his main account balance. I have three different wallet, bonus, referral and deposit and will like to sum up all of them together. This is already being recorded individually in the transaction history but I want the total sum to appear in the user dashboard.

| id | deposit | bonus | referral | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 200 | 15 | 5 |  |
| 13 | 320 | 21 | null |  |

The balance of user (10) is the sum total of deposit + bonus + referral, which is suppose to be 220 while user 13 balance is 341. How can this be achieve to display for each user?

Here is my model

```
`public function transactions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Transaction::class)->orderBy('id','desc');
}`
```

This is usercontroller

```
`public function transactions()
{
    $pageTitle = 'Transactions';
    $remarks   = Transaction::distinct('remark')->orderBy('remark')->get('remark');

    $transactions = Transaction::where('user_id', auth()->id())->searchable(['trx'])->filter(['trx_type', 'remark', 'wallet_type'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(getPaginate());
    return view($this->activeTemplate . 'user.transactions', compact('pageTitle', 'transactions', 'remarks'));
}`
```

Blade

```
 <li>
    <span class="caption">@lang('Main Balance')</span>
    <span class="value">{{ showAmount($transaction->post_balance) }}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to display sum of specific column

```
<span class="value">{{ showAmount($transaction->sum('post_balance')) }}</span>
```

Comment: Hello Chauhan, your code work I added forelse to div ad it seems to display some figure. However the figures do not match the total amount of the user. Seems like it is calculating the entire users transactions. How do I make it calculate  just for each user.

Comment: write your code here let me try to solve it

Comment: <span class="value">{{ showAmount(auth()->user()->sum('deposit_wallet + referral + bonus')) }}</span>

Comment: show me your showAmount() function

Comment: function showAmount($amount, $decimal = 2, $separate = true, $exceptZeros = false)
{
    $separator = '';
    if ($separate) {
        $separator = ',';
    }
    $printAmount = number_format($amount, $decimal, '.', $separator);
    if ($exceptZeros) {
        $exp = explode('.', $printAmount);
        if ($exp[1] * 1 == 0) {
            $printAmount = $exp[0];
        } else {
            $printAmount = rtrim($printAmount, '0');
        }
    }
    return $printAmount;
}

Comment: $transaction is in loop?

Comment: else say hi on my mail id chauhandharmesh1998@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

So far i know about the problem you may use laravel built-in sum method to perform sum of  deposit, bonus and referral for each row

Not tested but probably true

```php
public function transactions()
{
    $pageTitle = 'Transactions';
    $remarks   = Transaction::distinct('remark')->orderBy('remark')->get('remark');

    $userTransactions = Transaction::where('user_id', auth()->id())->searchable(['trx'])->filter(['trx_type', 'remark', 'wallet_type'])->orderBy('id', 'desc');
    $transactions = $userTransactions->paginate(getPaginate());

    $totalBalance = $userTransactions->get()->sum(function (array $transaction) {
         return (int) transaction->deposit + (int) transaction->bonus + (int) transaction->referral;
    });

    
return view($this->activeTemplate . 'user.transactions', compact('pageTitle', 'transactions', 'remarks', 'totalBalance'));
}
```

```php
 <li>
    <span class="caption">@lang('Main Balance')</span>
    <span class="value">{{ showAmount($totalBalance) }}</span>
</li>
```